# Iphone : Getting the Form Param using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm working on a app which will use a uiwebview to submit a form.
I wonder if it's possible to catch the post and parameters then reuse them to set a calendar event for ex.

I mean :
- fill the form (in webview)
- submit the form (in webview)
- catch form parameters and fill calendar event (native iphone framework).

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

br,
Smazimute

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for the `UIWebView` to your view controller, then implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method of the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. you can return NO from that to stop the actual page load and use it to grab the attempted web request.

I think that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding method in your UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

It is send before a web view begins loading content. From **request** you should be able to get post parameters

Comment: Hi all, thanks for this answer. Effectively, using this method and [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.formname.elementName.value"], i'm able to get all my field value. Thanks !